# How to override popup list view query(listViewProcess) in SuiteCRM?

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am trying to show the popuplist view for a certain WHERE clause however my code does not seem to get executed?

This is what I have in my custom/MODULE_NAME/views/view.popup.php:

```
<?php

if(!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');

class CustomRegistrationMetaViewPopup extends ViewPopup{

    public function listViewProcess(){

        parent::listViewProcess();

        $this->params['custom_select'] = "select * ";
        $this->params['custom_from'] = "from table ";
        $this->where .= "where condition = 'Verified'";
    }

    function CustomRegistrationMetaViewPopup(){
        parent::ViewPopup();
    }

    function preDisplay(){
        parent::preDisplay();
    }
}
```

My function never gets called. Any idea?

Comment: Where is your file placed? What version are you running?

Comment: Version 7.7.8
Sugar Version 6.5.24 (Build 509). The file was placed at custom/MODULE_NAME/views/view.popup.php

Comment: What is the name of the module?

Comment: If that's the location, then that's problem, should be custom/modules/MODULE_NAME.... etc.

Comment: Kratos, did moving the file help? Or was that a typo?

Comment: That was a typo. Exact same location and nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to override *listViewProcess* function which is available in listview. Correct place for file is: *custom\modules\MODULE_NAME\views\view.list.php*

and following is the helping code:

```
require_once('include/MVC/View/views/view.list.php');
class MODULE_NAMEViewList extends ViewList {

    function listViewProcess() {
        global $current_user;
        $this->params['custom_where'] = ' AND module_name.name = "test" ';

        parent::listViewProcess();
}

}
```